# Format LocalDateTime Response json

Tags: kotlin, jackson, javalin

I would like to format my LocalDateTime on Javalin.

I know the library uses Jackson to generate JSON and I also know how to configure it but where can I set the Jackson configuration?

I would like to format my dates in this format, "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss".

Thank you

Comment: This is a terrible idea. Use a standard ISO format, and format the date the way you want to in the presentation layer.

Comment: I try to mark my fields with "@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss")" but not work, what I need to do?

Comment: Again, don't do anything like that. Keep using the standard, ISO format. Format dates in the presentation layer, not in the JSON.

Comment: Ok, I will create a DTO with String field to set my LocalDateTime formated, thank you :), because the project is a test and I need to format output date to send

Comment: So, you'll do exactly what I advised not to do. And in an even worse way: now not only your JSON will be awful, but you will also corrupt your model.

Comment: I understand you about advice, but the project is a test to job and I need to format date to return, because this I'm asking, to try do the less worst way

Comment: I not setted this in my model, I did a DTO to return in my endpoint, is that a bad idea anyway?

Comment: Creating a DTO is not a bad idea. Using a field of type String when it should be of type LocalDateTime, and formatting in a non-standard, ambiguous format is.

Comment: What could I do in this DTO to solve my formatting problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Javalin, Jackson is configurable via `JavalinJackson#configure ()`.

In my specific case, I would do

```
JavalinJackson.configure(jacksonObjectMapper().findAndRegisterModules())
```

and then add the appropriate dependency:

```
compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.9.8"
```

Comment: Configure method from JavalinJackson is now deprecated. How to do this with Javalin version >= 4.0.0?

Comment: Well, it seems that we need to pass a object (that implement the JsonMapper interface from Javalin) to config.jsonMapper() method. This information can be found here https://javalin.io/documentation#faq

Answer (score 1):

You can format your LocalDateTime like this:

```
LocalDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss"))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're fine with using [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) (it handles LocalDateTime well):

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
JsonMapper gsonMapper = new JsonMapper() {
    @Override
    public String toJsonString(@NotNull Object obj) {
        return gson.toJson(obj);
    }
    @Override
    public <T> T fromJsonString(@NotNull String json, @NotNull Class<T> targetClass) {
        return gson.fromJson(json, targetClass);
    }
};
Javalin app = Javalin.create(config -> config.jsonMapper(gsonMapper)).start(7070);
```

Above code snippet is from the official documentation:  [javalin.io/documentation#faq](https://%20javalin.io/documentation#faq)